# Stitching images with append() in graphicsmagick

Tags: javascript, node.js, css-sprites, graphicsmagick

I have a large number of images stored on a separate server that needs to be displayed on a single page as a mosaic of some sort where the individual elements may be shown or hidden dynamically.

These images should be fetched, resized and then stitched together as a sprite, and used as background images on divs. Fetching and resizing is a non-issue at this point, as the biggest hurdle is understanding the append method, or rather how to add images to a set, in order to use said method.

According to the docs:

```
gm("img.png").append(ltr)
```

should:

```
Append a set of images
```

How do I get multiple images into a "set"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I could do, was as follows ...

```
var gm = require('gm')

gm('@images.txt')
  .append()
  .write('crazy.png', function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log('crazytown has arrived');
  })
```

Where images.txt is a list of images to append.

Have not yet been able to figure out how to pass a set of images other than an image list file.

Got the idea from the website - http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html

> When running a commandline utility, you can prepend an at sign @ to a filename to read a > list of image filenames from that file. This is convenient in the event you have too many > image filenames to fit on the command line.

Hope that helps
LeeT

Answer (score 4):

Let's say `images` is an array of path strings like this:

```
[ "/home/user/first.jpg", "/home/user/a.png", "/home/user/another.gif" ];
```

then this should work:

```
var gm = require('gm');

var gmstate = gm(images[0]);
for (var i = 1; i < images.length; i++) gmstate.append(images[i]);

// finally write out the file asynchronously
gmstate.write('/home/user/result.png', function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('Hooray!');
});
```

The idea is:

1. Start with a graphicsmagick state variable `gmstate`
2. Append to it in a loop synchronously.
3. `write()` does the real work, and this asynchronously.

This is equivalent to `gm('first').append('second').append('third')....append('last')`.

Perhaps it is possible to start with an empty state: `var gmstate = gm();`.

I have to admit that the `@` filelist hack in LeeNX's answer is a lot easier if you have a list in a file, but if you don't...?

**EDIT:** If you need to append the images horizontally, add a second parameter `true` to `append()`, like this:

```
gmstate.append(image, true);
```

Source: [Documentation for `append()`](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#append)

Comment: Hi, how to add para 'true' to append horizontally?

Comment: I am not a GraphicsMagick expert, but found something for you: http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#append says: `ltr` (optional): **true for left-to-right**, i. e. use `gmstate.append(images[i], true)`. Please tell me if this works, then I will update the answer.